# Macro Loops for Generation

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a template, like an excel form (CATALOG) that is needed to be generated into PDF and in another sheet, must be copied to another sheet and also to be saved in an excel form. I have a generate button where my macro is. But the problem is, it keeps looping as it keeps saving infinitely. I can't find what's wrong. Hope you can help. thanks in advance! :)
Here's the code:

```
Sub savetopdf()
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Dim MyDate As String
Dim client As String
Dim ref As Integer
Dim type1 As String
Dim NewBook As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Rows("27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("46").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("47").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("78").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("90").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("96").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATALOG").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 3").Visible = False

FilePath = "\\10.10.19.20\2017\5. SALES OPERATIONS\4. ENTERPRISE BUSINESS 
GROUP\CUSTOMER DATA BASE\Maintenance-Warranty Summary"
MyDate = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY")
ref = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATALOG").Range("G13").Value + 1
client = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATALOG").Range("C5").Value
type1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATALOG").Range("C16").Value


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATALOG").PageSetup
.CenterHeader = ""
.Orientation = xlPortrait
.PrintArea = "$B$2:$F$98"
.PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Address
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.FitToPagesWide = 1
End With

FileName = FilePath & "\" & MyDate & "_" & ref & "_" & client
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Catalog").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, 
FileName:=FileName, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
From:=1, _
To:=1, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

FileName2 = FilePath & "\" & MyDate & "_" & ref & "_" & client
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INVENTORY LIST").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
NewBook.SaveAs FileName:=FileName2, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATALOG").Range("G13").Value = ref
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, I am going to guess that you have a `Save` or `SaveAs` within a `Workbook_BeforeSave` or `Workbook_AfterSave` event, and you haven't set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before doing so.

Comment: What is calling the `savetopdf` procedure?  Just the button?

Comment: yep. the assigned macro of the button.

Comment: Well, I lost my bet with myself - was sure there was going to be something in the `Workbook` events that was causing the problem.  LOL.  Now I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Your code is working OK for me - no looping.

Comment: it saves continuously. I have to stop it by end task or if I clicked the design mode on time

Comment: All I can suggest is step through your code line by line and try to determine at what point it is re-invoking the procedure.  That might give us clues as to **why** it is re-invoking it.  (So, place a breakpoint on the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CATALOG").Range("G13").Value = ref` lines by clicking on those lines and pressing F9.  Then go to Excel, click your button and, when it stops at the breakpoint, start pressing F8.  See whether it finally gets to the `End Sub` or whether it starts running the code again before it gets that far.)